# Android: Show real time stamp on list view items

Tags: android, listview

In my application, i have a ListView with a Custom adapter containing data like an image, 3-5 TextViews.

This data is fetched from a web server, until now i am showing something

**This item is posted on Oct 10th 2012**

but i want to change it to something like

**This item is posted 6 days ago**

So, its something like refreshing the ListView every 1 min, I dont want to use `adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged()` or something like that, which reCreates the whole ListView with the new data.

I just want that TextView alone to change in background and get displayed on the UI.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to create a custom text view by extending the android TextView class and put a time task in it which update the text view message every one minute.

you can also use the

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#onVisibilityChanged(android.view.View, int) to start and stop the timer task.

Comment: You mean, a Custom TextView which has a Scheduled Action to update its  Text depending on the currentTime and a givenTime(Difference here) which is set as a parameter?.

Comment: SO in onDraw of this custom TextView i must do mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(){find the difference between times}??

Comment: You can actually start the timer when the visibility of the view changes and it become visible and stop the timer then the view is no longer visible. 

Now since you would be sub classing the TextView you don't need to override the onDraw() method. Just call the setText() method of the super class from the TimerTask with the new value..

Comment: But i need to create a timer and make scheduled tasks somewhere in the Custom TextView. Where to do that? I cant see anything like onCreate() in a TextView class to override.

Comment: try the link given in my answer... Please copy paste the link till int) to see the method. 

It is actually onVisibilityChanged() method in TextView which should be called when the visibility of the view changes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is supported out of the box.

Since it seems you already have a Date/Calendar at hand just convert it to relative time string with a function like this: http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/01/20/php-relative-date-time-string.html

If you want real-time updates, I think your best bet is to start a background thread giving it the ListView and update the visible items periodically, however you may want to update all of them to prevent inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0):

For Reference i suggest you to use below thing for change in ListView.

1.You need to get Row View for Particular item in which you want to change Textview.

2.Now from step 1 i believe you have your row view so apply change in it's child .